# Django annotate by sum of two values with multiple relations

Tags: django, django-annotate, django-subquery

I have 4 models:

```
class App(models.Model):
   ...

class AppVersion(models.Model):
   app = models.ForeignKey(App)
   version_code = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
        ordering = ('-version_code',)
   ...

class Apk(models.Model):
   version = models.OneToOneField(AppVersion)
   size = models.IntegerField()

class Obb(models.Model):
   version = models.ForeignKey(AppVersion)
   size = models.IntegerField()
```

`AppVersion` version always has one `Apk`, but may have 0, 1 or 2 `Obb`'s

I want to annotate QuerySet by total `size` of the `App` (which is `Apk.size` + sum of all `Obb.size` for given `AppVersion`).

My `App` QuerySet looks like this:

```
qs = App.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
```

and versions subquery is:

```
latest_versions = Subquery(AppVersion.objects.filter(application=OuterRef(OuterRef('pk'))).values('pk')[:1])
```

This subquery always gives the latest `AppVersion` of the `App`.

So what subquery should I use to annotate `qs` with `size` attribute calculated as shown above?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this - from my understanding you want an Apps apk, and obb sizes summed. `apk` and `obb_set` can be replaced by the fields related name if you added one. What I chose should be the defaults for a django OneToOne and Fk related name.

```
from django.db.models import F, Value, Sum, IntegerField

qs = App.objects.filter(
    is_visible=True
).annotate( 
    apk_size=Sum('apk__size'), 
    obb_size=Sum('obb_set__size')
).annotate( 
    total_size=Value( 
    F('apk_size') + F('obb_size'), 
    output_field=IntegerField()
)
```

Comment: One `App` has multiple `AppVersion`'s, I need `size` only for first `AppVersion` in the given queryset, but your suggested code will output sum of `Apk`'s and `Obb`s for all versions.

Comment: What does this model look like? `AndroidApplicationVersion`

Comment: sorry, I've edited the question — it's `AppVersion`.

Comment: What field determines which version is the latest?

Comment: Updated code in question once again. Latest version is with the biggest `version_code` (queryset is reverse-ordered by field `version_code`, so it's the first item in queryset).

Comment: thanks, would adding `.order_by('-version_code').first()` or `.order_by('-version_code')[0]` not work?